# NSURLSession HTTP basic auth delegate does not work

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I used `NSURLConnection` with challenge delegate, and it worked.
I now migrate my code to session, and challenge not called.
On server side I see 401 response, but no delegate called.

```
@interface MyDelegate : NSObject<NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>

@end

@implementation MyDelegate
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential * __nullable credential))completionHandler {
// Break point here NOT called
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential * __nullable credential))completionHandler {
    // Break point here NOT called

}
@end

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        //return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/123"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        req.HTTPMethod = @"PUT";
        [req setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        NSError *err;
        NSURLResponse *resp;
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:[MyDelegate new] delegateQueue:nil];
        [[session uploadTaskWithRequest:req fromData:[NSData new]]resume];
        sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

Do I miss something?

Just in case: please do not advice me to create Basic HTTP auth header manually, I want to use delegate.

PS: Could it be my delegate released since delegate not retained in session?
I will try to make it static, then.

Comment: NSURLSession objects retain their delegates just as NSURLConnection objects do.  So no, that's not the issue.

Comment: Hi, perhaps have you managed to solve this problem with the delegates of NSURLSession ... if so, It would be really helpful if you could post the solution here. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think NSURLSession requests have to be running in a run loop.  I'm not certain of this, however.

And of course, if you were doing this in a real app, you probably would not want to block the main thread with a sleep call.  This might also be part of the problem.